# Why does the effect of Enchantress not stack in Dominion?

Tags: dominion

In Dominion, if my opponent plays the [*Enchantress*](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Enchantress), this prevents my first action card from executing its instructions and gives me +1 Card and +1 Action instead.
My question is, what happens if my opponent plays *two* *Enchantress*es?
Will I get +2 Cards and +2 Actions on my first action card? I guess *No*, but I need an official source or convincing reasoning on this.

Initially, it might sound like the *Enchantress* is "replacing the instructions of the action card with +1 Card, +1 Action", and replacing it twice still leaves a single +1 Card, +1 Action.
But this is not the phrasing on the card:

> Until your next turn, the first time each other player plays an Action card on their turn, they get +1 Card and +1 Action instead of following its instructions.

The crucial word here is *"instead"*. I do not know how to interpret this exactly

One interpretation is as follows: the second *Enchantress* encounters the first action card, prevents its instructions from happening (even though they would not have happened anyway because of the first Enchantress) and gives me +1 Card and +1 Action, stacking with the first Enchantress,

The Wiki is not helpful on this, not addressing this point at all. Is there any official source telling me that I will get only +1 Card, +1 Action? Has anyone encountered this situation in the online game?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enchantress cannot stack; the first action played by an opponent will just give +1 card +1 action.

A quote from the creator/designer of Dominion confirms this:

> Throne / Enchantress does not give other players +2 Cards +2 Actions for their first Action played.

[Source](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=15393.msg599482#msg599482)

The reason it works this way is that Enchantress only does something when you would be otherwise following a card’s instructions; that comes from “instead of following it’s instructions”. So after the first enchantress has done it’s thing (whichever Enchantress you choose to follow first when playing a card); the second Enchantress no longer has anything to do, because there is no time at which you are about to follow the instructions that can be replaced.

The same idea applies to Trader (for original wording Trader; it has been updated to no longer use “instead”). When you would gain a card; you can reveal Trader to gain a Silver instead. Once you do that; you no longer “would gain” the card you would have gained; so you can’t reveal Trader again to gain yet another Silver. Only one Silver per card you would have gained.

> One interpretation is as follows: the second Enchantress encounters the first action card, prevents its instructions from happening (even though they would not have happened anyway because of the first Enchantress) and gives me +1 Card and +1 Action, stacking with the first Enchantress,

This interpretation disconnects the preventing of following instructions from the new thing you get instead. It would be correct if Enchantress said “the first time each other player plays an Action card on their turn, they do not follow its instructions. They get +1 Card and +1 Action.” With this; second Enchantress wouldn’t care if the instructions were going to be followed anyway. But as worded; Enchantress doesn’t fo anything if you were not going to follow the card’s instructions; because it needs the thing to replace.

Answer (score 6):

Because it is a replacement effect. The first one you play replaced it with +1 card and +1 action. The second one you play would replace that with +1 card and +1 action but that is the same so there really isn't a change.

Each additional one you play replaces the effect of the last one meaning it will always be +1 card and +1 action. This is important in case there is another card that also has a replacement like effect.

If they wanted them to stack they would have added text that indicates that and not just replace what happens.

Comment: This answer probably matches designer intent, but note that card text doesn't effect that. The replacement effect says that the *player* gets +1 card and +1 action instead of following the instructions on the card rather than the card's instructions being replaced with the new instruction  "+1 card and +1 action".

Comment: At first I thought this was the correct interpretation and had almost included it in my answer. But reading through various posts on the Dominion Strategy Forums; Enchantress is always referred to as making it so that instead of following instructions you do something different; which is subtly different than replacing the card’s instructions with new instructions. The card still has its original instructions; you just don’t follow them. Same conclusion; different reasoning.